# Wordpress - front-end file uploader

Tags: wordpress

Задача, нужно создать форму отправки поста в определенную категорию с front-end, как зарегистрированным так и нет пользователям.

С формой отправки все придельно ясно, а вот с File Uploader не совсем.

Вопрос как лучше всего организовать загрузку файлов (картинок)  ?

Есть ли в wordpress какие-то уже готовые варианты которые можно просто вынести на front-end и прикрутить к форме ?

Плагины не предлагать.

Comment: В WordPress готовых вариантов нет. Пишите код и приходите с ним сюда, когда будет конкретный вопрос. Писать за вас код не предлагать.

Comment: "Плагины не предлагать" А ты смешной.. Хочешь написать свой плагин, но корявый и дырявый.. :)

Comment: Нет, дело не в коде, в принципе понимание есть, но дело в другом, вопрос в том что возможно в wp уже есть функции которые просто можно перенести на front-end и не делать заного колесо. Вот о чем я. Если делать аплоадер с ноля на чистом php то в принципе проблем не должно быть.